# Is there any way I can insert the data based on the value of child in descending order in Firebase database?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am using java and android studio as IDE.

I want to save the value in the firebase database with the highest value at the top and insert the new data. If the new data have the value greater than the previous highest value then just move that highest value to a second child and make the new data highest value to the first child.

[image: ndroid s]

Comment: So you want to change the order in the Firebase console?

Comment: Yes, can we do so or not?